# Cannot resolve method setExpandedTitleGravity(int)

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, android-design-library, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout

I want to use [setExpandedTitleGravity()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setExpandedTitleGravity%28int%29) method from [CollapsingToolbarLayout](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html). I just migrated from eclipse to android studio. In eclipse it worked fine, but in android studio compiler gives me the error `cannot resolve method setExpandedTitleGravity(int)`.

Apparentely I'm using another version of the design library now, but it seems like it is the last one.
My gradle dependance is: `compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'`. Anyone knows why it happens?

Complete `build.gradle` file:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 22
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        compileOptions {
            sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
            targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:22.2.0'
}
```

Comment: post build.gradle . use compile `'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'`

Comment: then use `'com.android.support:design:23.0.0' `

Comment: Let me inform please

Comment: @IntelliJAmiya Thanks for the answer. `'com.android.support:design:22.2.1'` didn't help. For `'com.android.support:design:23.0.0'` it seems like I need to update build target to API 23, but it definetely worked using API 22 in eclipse, so probably that's not the case.

Comment: yeah .then try with `com.android.support:design:23.0.1'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You receive `cannot resolve method setExpandedTitleGravity(int)` because [setExpandedTitleGravity (int gravity)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.html#setExpandedTitleGravity(int)) is added in Design Support Library v23.0.0

You need to update your `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
}
```

To use support libraries v23 you also need to change `compileSdkVersion` to 23

Answer (score 1):

> cannot resolve method setExpandedTitleGravity(int)

Your **build.gradle** should be for **buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"**

```
 dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
              }
```

**`Note :`**  For your information `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0 rc3"` (Version `rc3`) is not stable .Probably Beta Version (Avoid Beta-Canary Version for perfect Result ) . It will be better way if you use stable version like `buildToolsVersion "23.0.0"` or its upper version .